# No Display Variable, Unity not working, Just upgraded to 13.04, have AMD drivers

Tags: 13.04, ati, graphics, radeon

I just upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04, and now my GUI / Unity is not working.  I get a login screen that looks fine, but when I log in, there are no menus or bars or anything, and all the tiles look grey and blocky.  I also can't move windows, even though I can open them (opening a terminal).

I have gnome and standard ubuntu unity installed.  Gnome seems to almost work, but is missing all the menus, and unity gives me a blank desktop with unmoveable windows.  Neither have any menus.

I've tried a few things, and I'll show all the output below.  I'm also copying the output from

(1) ccsm   -  Doesn't work, gives a GtK error for not being able to open a display.

Output:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ccsm", line 94, in <module>
    import ccm
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ccm.Conflicts import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm/Conflicts.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ccm.Constants import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm/Constants.py", line 30, in <module>
    CurrentScreenNum = gtk.gdk.display_get_default().get_default_screen().get_number()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_screen'
```

(2)  echo $DISPLAY

output is nothing.

(3)  unity

output is:

```
WARNING: no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to :0
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
unity-panel-service: no process found
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: decor
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".

This continues for a long time, and then I get: 


Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
```

(4)  Checking on graphics devices using lspci:

```
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV370 [Radeon X600/X600 SE] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 0b02
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 65
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at dcde0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        I/O ports at cc00 [size=256]
        Expansion ROM at dce00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [58] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Kernel driver in use: radeon

07:00.1 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV380 [Radeon X300/X550/X1050 Series] (Secondary)
        Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 0b03
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Memory at dcdf0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [58] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you *just* upgraded to 13.04, you may need to uninstall the AMD drivers and/or install them again from Software Sources > Additional Drivers.

Comment: How can I do this from the terminal?

Comment: To install `fglrx` drivers using the terminal, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI#Installing_via_the_command_line